# How do I hide a tag after selecting it in TiddlyWiki?

Tags: javascript, css, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

To prevent unnecessary tags from interfering on the screen, I want to hide them from the TagPickerTagTemplate selection list. This can be done?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPwyi.jpg)

Or at least hide tags after clicking? Something like this:
**onClick="this.style='visibility: hidden;'** for `<a>`

```
<a class="tc-btn-invisible" title="add tag"><span class="tc-tag-label tc-btn-invisible" style="background-color:;
fill:#333333;
color:#333333;">About</span></a>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest doing some reading about event listeners: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp
I would also suggest reading about how to formulate a question that people want to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This sounds like two different questions to me. Do you want to hide tags that have already been selected, or be able to define a property for each tag that describes whether it ever appears in the list -- or something else entirely?

Comment: I don't know how it works, I just want it to be convenient to use.

Comment: @mike2003 Please read the link Alexander Griffin commented about how to ask good questions on StackOverflow. We can answer targeted questions here when you clearly explain exactly what you're looking for, but "I want something that's convenient" isn't enough for us to figure out what you want an answer to.

Comment: There might be some way to achieve this with a [custom stylesheet](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Custom%20styles%20by%20data-tags) with conditions based on the tag, but I don't know enough about this. Afaik TW behaviour related to tags is meant to be systematic so it's not obvious that what you ask is possible with standard tags. Another approach would be to use a different field which would behave similarly to tags but customized for your needs, with some [customization of the view template](https://tiddlywiki.com/#SystemTag%3A%20%24%3A%2Ftags%2FViewTemplate) in order to display them.